# Can I change where root requests resolve to in an express app?

Tags: express

I've created a small Express app that essentially serves as a file browser for our department's work. Users can drag their files and folders onto a network drive, and the app presents this folder structure as a browsable web directory for my colleagues to view various simple static files such as html files, images, css and javascript.

This is extremely business critical, and has worked flawlessly for over a year now, but there is one feature that I'd like to add. Occasionally the work contained in a subdirectory is a slightly more complex project, and there would be a huge architecture/complexity benefit from it being able to reference files from its own root path. I'll try and explain with a small example:

```
/app
    /projects
        /project1
        /project2
            /index.html
            /styles.css
    /finished
        /project3
```

It would be great if there was a simple way I could declare the base url of project 2 to be /app/projects/project2 so that I could reference the css file from the html with href="/styles.css".

I've read that I could do this by creating a second express app for project2, and then route requests to /app/projects/project2 to that app, but this requirement crops up quite regularly and the thought of configuring/managing a multitude of sub apps without breaking the main viewer doesn't seem like fun!

Is there a simpler way? I'm thinking of a special designation in the subdirectory name e.g. "wwwproject2" that could get the app to adjust where it maps root requests to.

I'm sorry if this all sounds insane to those with more knowledge than me!

Comment: I've come up with some sort of solution outside of Express. I've converted all the links to be relative (e.g. href="styles.css"),  and am controlling where they resolve to with the <base> tag on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do that.
But you could simply reference it by using the relative path to it -> href="./styles.css"